# HtmlResponse from Scrapy doesn't retrieve the data from URL

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

These are the code run in Ipython.

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

response = HtmlResponse(url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_American_Games')
datas = Selector(response=response).xpath('//div[@class="thumb tleft"]')
```

When I execute `response` I got `<200 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_American_Games>`
But when I execute `reponse.body` I got `''` (NULL)

It seems like `HtmlResponse` doesn't retrieve any HTML's info for this page.

Does any know how to fix this?

FYI, if I ran `$ scrapy shell  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_American_Games` in command prompt then response won't be NULL.
I don't want to do the`scrapy shell url`way since I will be running for loop through the list of URL.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are not writting a spider here. `HtmlResponse` doesn't do any data retrieving from the internet so to say. What you have is only a response object with only the url attribute you've provided.

Here's is a great official depiction of architecture of scrapy: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html?highlight=scrapy%20architecture

However if you do want  to use scrapy features like selectors without scrapy spiders you can use `requests` to retrieve the page and continue on with scrapy `selectors`, `item loaders` etc. Though this is not recommended approach since you would be missing out on all of the features scrapy has to offer.

official scrapy tutorial for beginners: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want to be using Scrapy for this? Because if you do you should really follow the tutorial and use a Spider. I'm pretty sure this is not the way to use Scrapy.

If you just want a basic scraper in python 2 I suggest the following:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from lxml import html

response = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_American_Games')
page = html.fromstring(response.read())
datas = page.xpath('//div[@class="thumb tleft"]')
```